# Jmeter java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar doesn't pickup -t option

Tags: jmeter

If I used java -jar /absolute/path/to/ApacheJMeter.jar -t test.jmx, it just start the GUI without the test.jmx

If I used java -jar ./ApacheJMeter.jar -t test.jmx, it will show the GUI with test.jmx opened.

Thanks

Comment: I figured out that if I put jmeter and ApacheJmeter.jar in the same folder and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the absolute path to the -jar option you'll most likely need to include the absolute path to the test.jmx -t option.  E.x. `-t /absolute/path/to/test.jmx`, unless test.jmx happens to be in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

you should generally use:

- jmeter.sh for unix, linux, macosx
- jmeter.bat for windows